# How can I rewrite hamming code (7, 4) to (63, 57)

Tags: c, hamming-code

I have found hamming code (7, 4) I guess... but how to rewrite it to (63, 57).
If I have (7, 4) I enter 4 bits (3 redundant bits). So in (63, 57) I have to enter 57 bits?(from keyboard?) (6 redundant bits)
The code that I found:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    int data[10];
    int dataatrec[10], c, c1, c2, c3, i;
    printf("Enter 4 bits of data one by one\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &data[0]);
    scanf_s("%d", &data[1]);
    scanf_s("%d", &data[2]);
    scanf_s("%d", &data[4]);

    data[6] = data[0] ^ data[2] ^ data[4];
    data[5] = data[0] ^ data[1] ^ data[4];
    data[3] = data[0] ^ data[1] ^ data[2];

    printf("\nEncoded data is\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        printf("%d", data[i]);

    printf("\n\nEnter received data bits one by one\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        scanf_s("%d", &dataatrec[i]);

    c1 = dataatrec[6] ^ dataatrec[4] ^ dataatrec[2] ^ dataatrec[0];
    c2 = dataatrec[5] ^ dataatrec[4] ^ dataatrec[1] ^ dataatrec[0];
    c3 = dataatrec[3] ^ dataatrec[2] ^ dataatrec[1] ^ dataatrec[0];
    c = c3 * 4 + c2 * 2 + c1;

    if (c == 0 && dataatrec[6] == data[6] && dataatrec[5] == data[5] && dataatrec[3] == data[3]) {
        printf("\nNo error while transmission of data\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nError on position %d", c);

        printf("\nData sent : ");
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            printf("%d", data[i]);

        printf("\nData received : ");
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            printf("%d", dataatrec[i]);

        printf("\nCorrect message is\n");

        if (dataatrec[7 - c] == 0)
            dataatrec[7 - c] = 1;
        else
            dataatrec[7 - c] = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            printf("%d", data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use scanf with `%d`, the input will need to be separated by spaces.   If you just use `getchar`, the user could enter `1011` without spaces.  `scanf` is not your friend here.

Comment: yes, I'll change its behavior

Comment: Be careful, `getchar()` will read characters like `'0'` (48 in ASCII) and `'1'` (49 in ASCII) instead of integers line `0` and `1`.

Comment: So I need to write from keyboard 57 bits? or 4 bits